# Found an old wallet with transaction history with coins (unconfirmed), but no balance

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, wallet.dat

I have found an old bitcoin wallet in my files. I can see there are old transactions but they aren't confirmed. But there should be more BTC received than was sent, so there should be a balance. Is there anyway to get those transactions confirmed from 2013. And how do I check those addresses to see if there is any balance in those wallets?

Comment: Is your wallet fully synchronized?

Answer (score 2):

To check balance, just use this link: https://blockchain.info/address/your-wallet-address-here to check the balance of any wallet. You can also see all the transactions happened through that link.

Comment: Yes it's fully synced up. Let it run for a few days also,
How could I have the old transaction history but it's not ever on the block chain?

Comment: It can be a double spend, so over time,the transactions which was just broadcasted, but confirmed can revert.