# Found old Bitcoin wallet of mine, but has unconfirmed transactions from 2013

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

[image: Photo of wallet]

I found one of my old wallets.dat from way back, so I loaded it up and see that I had transactions but they never got confirmed. I can't remember if I just never let them run? But how would it be showing me the history if they never got confirmed? And is there a way to get them confirmed or to sync up so they will appear in my account balance?

I tried to send a small amount to the  wallet to wake it up haha. 
Any thoughts or tips?

[image: Photo of wallet]

Comment: Isn't this the same question as: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56458/found-old-wallet-with-transaction-history-with-coinsunconfirmed-no-balance ? If so, why post it twice

Comment: I've closed the previous question as a duplicate of this one, since the new one provides more detail.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the transactions on a blockexplorer? Your wallet should rebroadcast them if they are still valid.

Comment: Yes i have tried lookin it up on the block  chain and doesnt show anything, Should i just let my wallet run for a few days to see what happens? you can see they are incoming transactions from 2013 but not confirmed, wallet has been offline for years, is there a chance they might just show up?

Comment: Does the wallet have to stay on a connected to

Answer (score 1):

If they are outgoing transactions they will always appear regardless of how far behind the synchronization is. Any unconfirmed transactions will have long bounced back to your wallet by now. Try going on the command prompt (.cmd) on your computer and type in:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt" --zapwallettxes=1

Or try:

"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt" --zapwallettxes=1

Your bitcoin core wallet will re-scan and the bitcoins will show up on your wallet.

If they are incoming transactions that you are waiting for you will just have to leave the bitcoin core wallet open until it synchronizes to the date the bitcoins were received. This will probably take a few days.

Hope this helps...

James

Comment: They are incoming transations from 2013, my wallet is all synced up and up to date..

Answer (score 1):

In the case that these were actually still valid unconfirmed transactions, you might want to reimport that same wallet today, where the low fees that we're currently seeing might let these transactions confirm.

I'm suspecting that they might be still valid, because the wallet should have just dropped the transactions if the inputs were already spent.

Comment: Does the wallet have to stay connected and on to keep requesting the transaction

Comment: @bmoon: Yes, your wallet will broadcast the transactions only when you're online. However, you could export the raw transactions and submit them to exchanges directly, then you'd be able to get feedback regarding their validity directly.